# pure PHP not echoing without html tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, web-hosting

So I have a code that works fine in XAMPP, but when I uploaded it to 000webhost.com those php files without html tags on are not working.
For example

```
<?php echo "Hello";?>
```

would output nothing.
But this:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php echo "Hello";?>
</body>
</html>
```

would output hello.
Is there any way to just output a plain text without html tags, because i am using the page for ajax request. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: is your file extension is `.html`?

Comment: When it outputs nothing be sure to check the source. Maybe the browser just don't know how to render it.

Comment: there's no reason why this wouldn't work in theory. But the file extension would need to be .php. Does it output nothing when you view in the browser, or when you fetch via ajax, or both?

Comment: thanks for the reply, its a .php file, when it outputs nothing it outputs as <html><body></body></html>

Comment: in ajax its completely nothing. In browser <html><body></body></html>

Comment: @JustineCheRomero Are you checking the source or the developer window? If you send no tags they should not magically appear.

Comment: check if php is installed and configured in your host

Comment: http://opentraining.uphero.com/request_id.php this it the site its code is just <?php echo "hello" ?>

Comment: @JustineCheRomero I see "hello" on my screen...

Comment: in the developer window: <html><body></body></html>

Comment: really?? i'll try with other browser

Comment: @JustineCheRomero looks fine to me. http://imgur.com/a/BbjGc Hello on the page, and `<html><head></head><body>hello</body></html>` in the developer console. Chrome 58.0.3029.110

Comment: lol, its empty in mine. thanks for checking. Im currently downloading different browser to check

Comment: Thanks for your response. I asked my friends and they are saying there is a "hello". But I don't see in mine. Maybe I should update my browser. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: which browser you are using @JustineCheRomero

Comment: chrome, 58.0.3029.110